# Issues with np.unwrap() in python. Phaseshifting

Tags: python, shift, phase, unwrap

I have to plot a set of data which is in a 2-pi periodic box and there are discontinuities because of the periodicity of the values, so I used the numpy function unwrap() for discontinuities in pi or 2*pi, but it doesn't solve my problem.

Below is the plot. It is noticeable that between ~3 and ~5, there is a discontinuity, but unwrap() doesn't notice (or solve) it.

Any suggestion is appreciated
[image]

Comment: could you provide some copyable data? see [mcve]